# Find out types of method parameters with modisco

Tags: java, eclipse

how do I find types of method parameters with MoDisco?

Like `java.lang.String` and `foo.bar.MyType` for `public void myMethod(String s, MyType mt){/*..*/}`

I have already tried to get `AbstractMethodDeclaration javaOperation` resembling `myMethod`, then calling

```
EList<SingleVariableDeclaration> parameters = javaOperation.getParameters();
```

Then for each `parameter` in `EList<SingleVariableDeclaration> parameters` called `parameter.getType().getType()` to get an object of type `org.eclipse.gmt.modisco.java.Type`.

And all I can do from this point is to get the name of the type itself, e.g. `MyType`, and there is no hint how to get packages names for that type (API doc http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.modisco.doc%2Fjavadoc%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fgmt%2Fmodisco%2Fjava%2Fclass-use%2FExpression.html).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

P.S. Is there any decent MoDisco docs on the Internet? Because official API docs are not very informative, just a little excerpt:

> Returns the value of the 'Usages In Type Access' reference list. The
>   list contents are of type TypeAccess. It is bidirectional and its
>   opposite is 'Type'.
>
> If the meaning of the 'Usages In Type Access' reference list isn't
>   clear, there really should be more of a description here...

Sure it should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I only have a dirty workaround: find all available types for a project and store them in `List<TypeDeclaration> allTypes`.

Then I use the following code:

`for(TypeDeclaration td: allTypes){
    if(td.getName().equals(paramTypeName)){
    td.getPackage(); // Do something
    }
 }`

Sure there should be more elegant way to do that. Any help is still greatly appreciated.